# Trouble trying to find ActionType for "execute_trajectory" Action Server

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and working with the Panda robot from Franka Emika.

I'm currently trying to send a command to the robot via Python scripting, i.e Action Client.

I can already send commands to the robot (like stopping it) through the command line, like:

```
$ rostopic pub -1 /execute_trajectory/cancel actionlib_msgs/GoalID "stamp:
  secs: 0
  nsecs: 0
id: ''"
```

And i would like to do the same but with Python, so i tried the following:

```
import actionlib
import rospy
from actionlib_msgs.msg import GoalID
from franka_control.msg import ErrorRecoveryAction, ErrorRecoveryActionGoal


def stop_robot():
    rospy.init_node('panda_STOPP')
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('execute_trajectory', GoalID)
    client.wait_for_server()
    goal = GoalID()
    goal.goal_id.stamp.secs = 0
    goal.goal_id.stamp.nsecs = 0
    goal.goal_id.id = ''
    goal.goal = {}
    client.send_goal(goal)

if name == '__main__':
    stop_robot()
```

It doesn't work because GoalID is not an action type message. And in order to create the Client we need one Action message. And i find it strange that there is no action message for GoalID because "execute_trajectory" is actually an action server, meaning there should be an action message for it, right? I don't know if understood the concept of Actions wrongly but any help would be welcome!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307462/trouble-trying-to-find-actiontype-for-%22execute_trajectory%22-action-server/) by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2018-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using MoveIt to control your robot? If so all the messages, services and action types are [described here](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_msgs). You'll need the [ExecuteTrajectory action](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/action/ExecuteTrajectory.html) to command the arm.

To clarify a goal and a trajectory are different things. A goal is the desired pose of the end effector (and possibly gripper state too) but a trajectory is a matrix of joint angles defining how they change over time that the robot can follow. You can generate a trajectory from an initial robot state and a goal using a motion planning algorithm.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on 2018-11-05**:
Hey Pete, yes, i'm using MoveIt to control it, i just didn't realized that actually MoveIt was generating this execute_trajectory. I'm going to try this out and then give you a feedback. Thank you very much for your explanation and answer!